# Jenkins won't kill node.exe?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, jenkins

I've got a Jenkins job set up to run a node.js server in the background, perform some tests on it (through a batch script, using Nightwatch), and then kill off the node server using the TaskKill batch command. Here's the command line script I have for the build:

```
START /B node ../app.js
runtests.bat
taskkill /F /IM node.exe
```

The build runs and passes, but it never seems to kill node. At the end of the console output I get:

`Process leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information`

And I can see the node.exe process still running in my Task Manager.

If I run the same commands in my own command prompt it works fine, and kills node. It's just that Jenkins doesn't seem to execute that last command at all.

Any ideas? Am I maybe taking the wrong approach altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to get it working by installing the Hudson Post Build Task plugin, and just killing node in a post-build command. Still not sure why it wasn't working before though.